# Correct launch.json for VS Code to attach to a port of a running nodejs process

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, skaffold

I'm trying to get the following setup to work in the VS Code nodejs process. The actual process is already calling `node --inspect`, and the [skaffold debug](https://skaffold.dev/docs/workflows/debug/) tool is porting it over to localhost for me:

```
Port forwarding pod/tickets-depl-64bfdfcbb-lgcrw in namespace default, remote port 9229 -> 127.0.0.1:9229
```

The container is set up like this:

```
/
  app/
    src/  -- sources in typescript
    build/ -- output of tsc, with the .js files and the .map files.
```

On my Mac, the VS Code project directory has:

```
[project dir]/
  ticketing/  -- micro-service under the project
    src/  -- original source files
    Dockerfile
    ...
```

I've tried all kinds of things for launch.json. Here's what I have now:

```
    {
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
      // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
      // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Attach to Ticketing Port",
          "protocol": "inspector",
          "request": "attach",
          "address": "localhost",
          "port": 9229,
          "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
          ],
          "type": "node",
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/tickets/src",
          "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/tickets/build/**/*.js"],
          "remoteRoot": "/app/src",
          "trace": true
        
        },
      ]
    }
```

This connects with the project, but I cannot set breakpoints in my source files, and my source files do not appear in loaded files.

This is not an uncommon problem, but I'll admit I don't find much in the way of good advice as to what to do. Is VS Code currently broken in Version: 1.56.2, or is this just very, very hard to get right?

In case this is related to how I'm generating the source maps, here's tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "__test__",
    "**/__mocks__/*",
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/test/setup.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                       /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: The breakpoints issue turned out to be how skaffold parsed my Dockerfile -- the closer you get to ending with a simple CMD that directly calls node, the better. But the current launch.json is trying to find my build files locally, on my Mac, at /apt/build. What I *want* to do is to have it get at the map files on the docker container. Must I manually download the build files from the container and sym-link them to /apt/build on my Mac? That sounds crazy.

Comment: Any resolution you could share @torenware Networks?

Comment: I'm not sure if I solved this one or not; it having been 2 years since I last looked at this. What have you tried? VSCode may have fixed this, or just have different bugs :-)